# Convergence of a sub-sequence

Tags: convergence-divergence, inner-products

I am having a doubt about the convergence of a sub-sequence as follows. 
Knowing that sequences $x(k),y(k) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ converge to $x^*, y^*$ respectively as $k$ goes to $0$ ($k \in \mathbb{R}^+$). We also have $<x(k), y(k)> = k$. So, $<x^*, y^*> = 0$.
Now I divide both sides of the inner product by $k$ and consider $<x(k), \frac{y(k)}{k}> = 1$.
My question is when $k$ goes to $0$, whether I can prove the limit of $\frac{y(k)}{k}$ to a certain point $\hat{y}$?

Comment: Are $x(k)$ and $y(k)$ series or sequences?

Comment: Doesn't $x(k)=y(k)=\sqrt{k}$ give a counterexample in $\mathbb R^1$?

Comment: @Evan: I mean it's the sequence. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: If it's a sequence, then the index $k$ should be discrete. The index of sequences normally runs over the numbers $1, 2, 3\dots$ in an ascending order toward infinity, and not as in your example over $\mathbb{R}_+$ in a descending order toward $0$.

Comment: @EvanAad In my context, $x(k)$ and $y(k)$ are the sequences whose values depend on the parameter $k > 0$ (maybe the word "sequence" leads a misunderstanding for you, but I don't know a better word for describing). That's why I avoid to use the notations $x_k, y_k$ for my case.